# fengyuanchen cropper is not showing cropped image without page reload in bootstrap modal. It saves first image

Tags: jquery, crop, bootstrap-modal

I have used fengyuanchen/cropper v0.9.2 for image crop and rotation in bootstrap modal. It's working fine for both crop and rotation but problem is that it saves the first image in modal after crop, suppose I have opened an image in modal, crop it, save it(from the server) and dismiss the modal. Then if I open the image again but it is showing the old image not the cropped one. But if I reload the page then it is showing cropped one. Below is some code that I have used.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.original_image_show', function() { //click on the image 
var data_original = $(this).find('img').attr('data-original');/ //get the src to to crop
 // #originalImageShow is the modal div's id.
$("#originalImageShow").find(".bootstrap-modal-cropper img").attr('src', data_original); //set the src of bootstrap modal from clicked image's src.


var $image = $('.bootstrap-modal-cropper > img');
$('#originalImageShow').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      //-----cropping code here-----
        }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $image.cropper('destroy');//I have used this code to destroy the modal.
 });
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the problem, It was for caching of image. When I click the image first, then browser cached the image and next it shows the old image from cache not the cropped one.

```
var data_original = $(this).find('img').attr('data-original');/ //get the src to to crop
var data_original = data_original+ '?'+Math.random()*Math.random();
 // #originalImageShow is the modal div's id.
$("#originalImageShow").find(".bootstrap-modal-cropper img").attr('src', data_original); //set the src of bootstrap modal from clicked image's src.
```

By adding " '?'+Math.random()*Math.random()" with the src of image solved the the caching problem.